# using needs-lock in subversion in Netbeans 7.4

Tags: svn, netbeans, locking

We are two developers working on the same `Java Application`. Both of us use `Netbeans 7.4` and `subversion`. 
Our problem is that we don't like `merge` model. We want that if someone starts editing the file, the other one can not make any changes to the file. 
To active this, I tried `needs-lock` feature of `subversion`. I right clicked on a file `Subversion/Properties` in the `Netbeans`. In the opened window, I choosed `Property Name:` svn:needs-lock `Property Value:` *. I guess this is the way to lock files automaticly but it didn't work. When I set `needs-lock` property, the other developer can still edit the file without any warning! 
How can we achive that we want?

Comment: Did you commit your change? Did the other developer update his working copy? Files will not be locked automatically by any client that I'm aware of (except if you mount a share via WebDAV) - you need to explicitly lock a file before working on it.

Comment: Regardless, learn to love the copy-modify-merge model. I've worked with the lock-modify-unlock model. It can be painful and reduce productivity. There is a reason every modern VCS (that I'm aware of) has ditched it.

Comment: @alroc you are right, when i commit the change and other developer update his working copy it worked. But it is not practical. We didn't find it an easy and stable way of doing that. Because everytime i need to lock a file, i should tell the other developer to update his working copy of the file. Maybe we should learn copy-modify-merge model as you suggested.

Comment: OK, so what you've observed is **the way Subversion was designed to work**. But yes, learn the modern way of working. It's better for everyone.